# Is it possible to put @media screen rules in a for loop?

Tags: css

I have @media screen rules in my css file and they look like the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: calc((180px + 40px) * 1 - 40px)) {
  #main-form {
    width: calc((180px + 40px) * 1 - 40px);
  }
  #main-projects {
    width: calc((180px + 40px) * 1);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: calc((180px + 40px) * 2 - 40px)) {
  #main-form {
    width: calc((180px + 40px) * 2 - 40px);
  }
  #main-projects {
    width: calc((180px + 40px) * 2);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: calc((180px + 40px) * 3 - 40px)) {
  #main-form {
    width: calc((180px + 40px) * 3 - 40px);
  }
  #main-projects {
    width: calc((180px + 40px) * 3);
  }
}
```

As you can see, they are identical except for the multiplying numbers being increased.

Is it possible to put these into a for loop in a css file so I can reduce my code?

Comment: It is possible with sass https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge you cannot write for loops in css. However, you can in SASS. Check out the link below for examples:

https://www.koderhq.com/tutorial/sass/iteration-control/